# SMS queue priority handling

Tags: java, queue

I have more logical problem than programming and decided to ask here.
I should create a bulk sms system which have limited throughput. The operator can send only 2 SMS/sec. I have SMS site where the clients could schedule bulks. Each bulk contains different number of SMSes (1000, 2000, 10 000, etc.) and could be scheduled at any time. The problem comes when 2 or more bulks are scheduled for the same time, for example at 15:00 o'clock. I want to execute all bulks depending of what priority have each of them, meaning that non of them will be executed first and then the second, third, etc. but  for example to send 3 SMSes from the bulk with biggest priority then 2 SMSes with the lower and then 1 from the one with smallest priority and then continue in the same way until all the SMSes are sent.
I am searching for some kind of queue maybe but could you suggest any good solution and data structure appropriate for my case?

My solution will be in Java!

Thanks

Comment: Doy have DB table for all this SMSes?

Comment: yes, Every SMS will be record in a db and will have priority number

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have 2 tables in DB:

1. SMSes (id, text, status, bulk_id)
2. Bulks (id, priority)

You can organize priority, by getting all bulks, then sort them in that order you want to process them.(Or query them already sorted) For each bulk get as many SMSes as you want (by priority) and send them, then mark them as "sended".
You will know that bulk are processed, when there are no SMSes for this bulk with status "ready to send".

This approach have disadvantage that you have more load on DB, but you have VERY narrow place (2SMS/sec), so that wouldn't be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you were fetching messages of the highest priority then a simple priority queue would have worked, in memory or from the db. But you intend to fetch some messages from all the queue. Here is a crude implementation to give you an idea. You can extrapolate it to bulk scenario.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public final class NQueue
{
    private final List<Deque<String>> queues = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int[] poll;
    private int currentIndex;
    private int queueIndex;
    private final int pollWidth;

    public NQueue(int[] poll)
    {
        this.poll = new int[poll.length];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < poll.length; i++)
        {
            int val = poll[i];
            sum += val;
            this.poll[i] = sum;
            queues.add(new LinkedList<>());
        }
        this.pollWidth = sum;
    }

    public synchronized void addMessage(String msg, int priority)
    {
        queues.get(priority).add(msg);
    }

    public synchronized Optional<String> removeMessage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.pollWidth; i++)
        {
            updateQueueIndex();
            String msg = queues.get(queueIndex).poll();
            currentIndex++;
            if (msg != null)
            {
                return Optional.of(msg);
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private void updateQueueIndex()
    {
        if (currentIndex == pollWidth)
        {
            currentIndex = 0;
            queueIndex = 0;
        }
        else if (currentIndex == this.poll[this.queueIndex])
        {
            queueIndex++;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample client.

```
//in every run, poll 3 from priority 0, 2 from priority 1 and 1 from priority 2
NQueue nQueue = new NQueue(new int[]{3,2,1});

nQueue.addMessage("a",0);
nQueue.addMessage("b",1);
nQueue.addMessage("c",2);
nQueue.addMessage("d",1);
nQueue.addMessage("e",0);
nQueue.addMessage("f",1);
nQueue.addMessage("g",1);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Optional<String> s = nQueue.removeMessage();
    System.out.println("s = " + s);
}
```

it prints

```
s = Optional[a]
s = Optional[e]
s = Optional[b]
s = Optional[d]
s = Optional[c]
s = Optional[f]
s = Optional[g]
s = Optional.empty
s = Optional.empty
s = Optional.empty
```